# Update multiple select dropdown to mysql database without deleting all the existing rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have to update the multiple select dropdown into the database, but without deleting all the existing rows.
I have two table `num` and `multipleselect`. Which i have listed below.

```
+--------+----------+
| num_id | num_name |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | One      |
|      2 | Two      |
|      3 | Three    |
+--------+----------+
```

Here's the table i want update the `numid` values.

```
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
| multipleselect_id | multipleselecttrackerid | numid |
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|                14 | 5                       |     1 |
|                15 | 5                       |     3 |
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Here's the `Edit` page code

```
<?php
// PK table
$sqlNum = "SELECT * FROM num";
$resultNum = mysqli_query($con, $sqlNum);

// FK table
$sqlChildren = "SELECT numid FROM multipleselect WHERE multipleselecttrackerid = $URLiD";
$resultChildren = mysqli_query($con, $sqlChildren);
$selectedChildren = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($resultChildren, MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'numid');
?>

<select name ="fm_multiple[]" multiple>
    <?php
    while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNum)){
        $selectedNumId = $parent['num_id'];
        $selectedNumName = $parent['num_name'];
        $selected = in_array($selectedNumId, $selectedChildren) ? "selected='selected'": '';
        echo "<option value='{$selectedNumId}' {$selected}>{$selectedNumName}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

...and the output.

```
<select name="fm_multiple[]" multiple="">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Three</option>
</select>
```

So far everything works great. Now i want to reselect the dropdown items and update to database. I want to UPDATE with the existing row. I do not want to delete all the rows first and then insert.
I had the same issue in the checkbox which i was able to achieve using hidden value.

Just to clarify things. 
Lets say i edit the drop-down and select only `One` and `Two` and remove `three`.

So in the table i am looking for this, the `multipleselect_id` `15` is deleted and added `16` for numid 2

```
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
| multipleselect_id | multipleselecttrackerid | numid |
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|                14 | 5                       |     1 |
|                16 | 5                       |     2 |
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

not this.

```
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
| multipleselect_id | multipleselecttrackerid | numid |
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|                16 | 5                       |     1 |
|                17 | 5                       |     2 |
+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: `I do not want to delete all the rows first and then insert.` Why not?

Comment: Just wondering, Is there any other way.? ...other than deleting all the rows first.